# Does Jython need the Selenium2 library for java version to run?

Tags: java, python, automation, jython, robotframework

I've been using Python to run test scripts from the command line and have been asked by collegues to look into the java variant of Robot Framework. I've learned that you need Jython for the java variant, so after installing Jython and making it usable from the command line I have tried to run my test cases only for for a large error to be thrown at me:

`[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Python\AdminTests\AdminResource.txt': Importing test library 'Selenium2Library' failed: SyntaxError: future feature unicode_literals is not defined (selenium.py, line 17)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library__init__.py", line 2, in 
    from keywords import *
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library\keywords__init__.py", line 3, in 
    from _browsermanagement import _BrowserManagementKeywords
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library\keywords_browsermanagement.py", line 4, in 
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium__init__.py", line 15, in`

If it's not me needing to install the other Selenium2 library then what have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A long time ago Selenium ceased being compatible with Jython 2.5. You should be able to install Jython 2.7 beta and continue using the Python Selenium2Library.

Alternatively, you could switch to using the [Java port of Selenium2Library](https://github.com/MarkusBernhardt/robotframework-selenium2library-java).

Yet another alternative is to continue executing under Python and use all Java through the remote library API using [jrobotremoteserver](https://github.com/ombre42/jrobotremoteserver).

Comment: What would I have to import to use the Selenium 2 for Java lib? I can't seem to find the documentation for it. :(

Comment: You still use the same "Library Selenium2Library" declaration. You have to make sure that the Java version is found before the Python version if it is present, otherwise you will get the same error.